# How to enable virtualization AMD (can't find in BIOS)

Tags: android, virtual-machine, amd-processor

I'm trying to enable virtualization on my PC. I currently have Ryzen R5 1600 with a ASRock AB350 MOBO. I have tried looking for the AMD-V in BIOS and have made sure that SVM is turned on in my BIOS. I am on Windows 10 Home. I can't seem to find it.

I'm trying to enable this so I can emulate an Android device. Has anyone ran into something like this before?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Try this: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-enable-hardware-virtualization-in-Windows-10-and-how-do-I-resolve-the-following-error-message-in-Android-Studio-1-3-1

Comment: Thank you for that. I have went through every option I could find to no avail. I may have to contact the manufacturer to see if it's even in the BIOS...

Comment: It could be helpful: https://www.reddit.com/r/Amd/comments/603s4i/virtualization_on_ryzen/

Comment: Hmm - I'm going to have to try what the last guy did. Install hyper-v and then uninstall it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ryzen is not supported by android studio**

Windows 10 home dont have the option of virtualization/hyper-v at all, and even if you install windows 10 pro version you cant use it *due to intel monopoly*.

although you can use the virtual ADB by installing arm based emulator, which is super slow as you cant use your GPU to compliment the power.

**instead use bluestacks:- keep in mind to run bluestacks before android studio.**

keep in mind to enable SMT and SVM from bios (usually located at OC page)

My PC Specs:
Ryzen 1700
32 GB 2400Mhz RAM
960 EVO M.2 NVMe
500 GB HDD
GTX 1050ti