# Virtualization in AMD Processors

Tags: android, virtual-machine, virtualization, amd-processor

greets. After getting a decent computer to start coding I realized that AMD processors can't run [HAXM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25263360/intels-haxm-equivalent-for-amd-on-windows-os/43505984#43505984)... and that is pretty much it, please help:

- I already got in the BIOS and activated the SVM ([in case it's not on the BIOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45179066/how-to-enable-virtualization-amd-cant-find-in-bios))
- AMD FX-8320E
- I have only be able to find old posts with dead links to other posts
- Android Studio
- Kotlin

Any sugestions please.

- it was sugested for AMD to [create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30405740/android-studio-how-can-i-make-an-avd-with-arm-instead-of-haxm) a device, and in the "ABI" column it has to say: ARM EABI v7a or ARM 64 v8a
- it was sugested to
- Windows right click Windows Button
- Select "Apps and Features"
- "Programs and features"
- "[Turn Windows Features on and off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30405740/android-studio-how-can-i-make-an-avd-with-arm-instead-of-haxm)"
- In the displayed list select Hyper-V checkbox == Make sure the subfolders are 
  all selected.
- When prompted to restart, restart the PC.
- After restart and update instalation screen you are back in Windows and you 
  should be able to run the Emulator.

---

- New update: the Windows version has to be pro, no emulator will work on home 
  edition, I do have pro

---

- New edit Emulator: Enable via Windows Features: "Windows Hypervisor Platform". 
  Restart. No need for Hyper-V and Win10 Pro.
- After this the emulator just showed: "Process finished with exit code 
  -1073741819 (0xC0000005)"

---

- Well I finally gave up, I reinstalled a brand new downloaded version of 
  Windows, made with the official tool offered in their [site](https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/software-download/windows10)
- After that I re-followed all the steps I collected from the other question that were given, trying to open the virtual device between each new step.
- and Voilá! after 2 windows installations and a lot of "steps" it did work, Idk the exact thing that made it worked (it started working exactly at the step where you check Hyper-V checkbox)

Hope it helps if you ever find yourself stuck in something like this, you can't check the links in the question for more.

Comment: Hi Wallace, thank you for your question; at present it appears to be a duplicate. If it's not just ping me (include @nanofarad in your comment so I get a notification) and I'll go ahead and reopen if it's not a good match.

Comment: @nanofarad Yes, the duplicate post is kind of old, years, it offers solutions that I have already done and added by editing my question, besides the duplicate is still unsolved and open.

Comment: Which version of Windows 10. Also as a test, make sure you are not running any other virtualization software (Docker, VMware, etc.). Also as Ryzen is recommend and your processor is rather old, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43505984/295004

Comment: Windows Pro as I said, no other vSoftware, It's a brand new clean install of windows, AMD documentation reveals AMD FX 8320E would run android virtual devices (The board, graphic card, ram, sdd and others as well) Thanks, the post did not have any aditional info